# How to assign a shallow copy of an item of a list to an attribute of a class

Tags: python, list, copy, shallow-copy

Imagine having a list like

```
L = [a, b, c, d]
```

and a class `cl` with an attribute `at`.

What I want to do is to set the to a value from that list *without* copying the value. For example, I want to set:

```
cl.at = L[1]
```

but the `L[1]` to be a shallow copy of the list `L`, so, if `L[1]` changes
then `cl.at` changes as well.

Comment: You can't do that in Python - if `L[1]` is immutable, then there is no way for changes to `cl.at` to alter `L`. If `L[1]` *is* mutable, then you already have the behaviour you want.

Comment: If the list is stored on the same instance you want to access the attribute on, you can make this work by defining a property `at` that gets and sets the element with index 1 in the list.  If that's not your use case, please give a bit more context on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if i say cl.at = L[2] and L[2] is a mutable class object, will the computer copy the value of L[2] consuming memory, or it will work as a "pointer"?

Comment: @aggelosgaraleas it will work as a pointer; unless you explicitly create a copy, assignment in Python creates a reference to the same object.

Comment: @aggelosgaraleas: The accepted answer in the linked question (the "duplicate target") covers this pretty well, but you may find this article interesting: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.